# How can (-1 >= sizeof(buffer)) ever be true? Program fail to get right results of comparison

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, heap-pollution

The program runs into impossible execution routine, where `if( len >= sizeof(buff) )` should never be true in reality, however it happens. As is shown by the `printf` output `len:-1__1024`: `len`, whose value is -1, is larger than  `sizeof(buff)`, which is 1024. It's amazing.

```
select return value -1 ,4
select: Interrupted system call
-1_0x66a1e0
len:-1__1024  
*** glibc detected *** /home/fang/Desktop/work/fw: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000066a1e0 ***
```

The following is the execution code.

```
while (1) {
        if( len >= sizeof(buff) ) {   //here len==-1, sizeof(buff)==1024
            printf("len:%d__%d  %s\n", len, sizeof(buff), tmp1); //oops
            free(tmp1);
            tmp1 = buff;
        }
        len = get_next_event(&tmp1, sizeof(buff));
        printf("%d_%p\n",len, tmp1);
        if( len > 0 ){
            tmp = strtok_r(tmp1, "\n\r", &saveptr);
            // ignore following codes ......
```

I think the bug is resulted from the stack pollution, but it's hard to find out the secret. To mention more, I list the code of function `get_next_event`. Wish for your help ^_^

```
int get_next_event(char **buf, int len)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    int tmp;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr; 

    sin_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&fdsr);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &fdsr);
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    if (new_fd != 0) {
       FD_SET(new_fd, &fdsr);
    }

    tmp = select(maxsock + 1, &fdsr, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (tmp < 0) {
       printf("select return value %d ,%d\n", tmp, errno);
       perror("select");
       return -1;
    } else if (tmp == 0) {
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Does your compiler print some "signed/unsigned mismatch" warnings or similar when you compile?

Comment: Yes, I ignored these warning

Comment: @river  Note that posting the warning received helps 1) diagnosing the problem 2) makes the post more valuable as others may find this based on a search of the warning.

Comment: You get a warning. You ignore it. You find strange behaviour in the same line. And you still don't think, handling the warning or telling us about it might be a good idea?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I should take serious care about these warnings. In fact, gcc doesn't give me the warning of the comparison statement. @Gerhardh

Comment: Can you give me a better title to describe my post? GCC doesn't give me any warning about `int i = -1 ;  if( i > sizeof(i) ) { printf("%d\n", i); }`  @chux

Comment: What about "How can (-1 >= sizeof(buffer)) ever be true?"

Comment: @river [I ignored these warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489839/how-can-1-sizeofbuffer-ever-be-true-program-fail-to-get-right-results-o?noredirect=1#comment89959653_51489839) and [GCC doesn't give me any warning about...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489839/how-can-1-sizeofbuffer-ever-be-true-program-fail-to-get-right-results-o?noredirect=1#comment89989730_51489839) imply compilation generated some warnings for something.  Posting those warnings adds value to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -1, is larger than  sizeof(buff). It's amazing.

It is.

`len >= sizeof(buff)` is the same as `-1 >= sizeof(buff)`  same as `(size_t)-1 >= sizeof(buff)` --> `SIZE_MAX >= sizeof(buff)` --> which is certainly true.

When an `int` like `len` is compared to the *unsigned* type `size_t`, the result of `sizeof`, one of the types is converted to the other based on which have a wider range.

In this case, it is usually the `int` converts to the *unsigned* `size_t`.  `(size_t)-1` is the greatest value of `size_t` and is certainly larger than `sizeof(buff)`.

---

It is unclear why `len == -1` without seeing more code.

Yet in this case, I'd recommend to use `size_t len = 0` to mend code.

---

When printing, use the a matching print specifier like `"%zu"`

```
printf("size:%zu\n", sizeof buff);
```

OP's code, lacking a warning, with `printf("%d\n", sizeof(buff));` implies warnings are not fully enabled.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.